# MySQL rows in explain extended keeps increasing while the rows are being deleted continuosly

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.6, index-tuning

I have a table in Mysql with userid, status and other columns. I keep updating the status of the row as and when the job is complete. Periodically these rows are deleted from the table.

```
JobTable (userid, status, ...)
   userid_status_index (userid, status)
```

When I run some queries:

```
   select count(*) from JobTable where userid="1" and status="ready"
   Result: 20
```

For explain:

```
   explain extended select count(*) from JobTable force index (userid_status_index) where userid="1" and status="ready"
   rows: 2500
```

When I do explain, the number of rows keeps increasing (as I keep inserting, but the deleted rows are probably not removed from the index), but when i do count(*) on the actual table, it shows lesser rows.
After few rows, the DiskIOPS increases and things are back to normal. I suppose this is due to some change buffer update. Can I force it to happen more periodically so that the queries are not slow?

Forcing the index also doesn't help.
Also note that the queries are actually slow when it's run, not just the explain is incorrect.

Mysql 5.6

Comment: The rows amount value reported by EXPLAIN is approximate. Renew table statistic for to receive fresh values.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the *real* query?

```
select count(*) from JobTable where userid="1" and status="ready"
```

If so, here's how it works when you have `INDEX(userid, status)` *or* `INDEX(status, userid)`

1. It drills down the index's BTree to the first entry with that pair of values.
2. Count 1.
3. Scan forward until the pair no longer matches (else back to step 2).

The only thing that can change is the details of the BTree.  `INSERTs` and `DELETEs` may lead to block splits and block merges.

Don't trust the numbers in `EXPLAIN`.

In this case, there is no benefit in using `FORCE/USE INDEX`; the index to use is too obvious.  (Or do you have a case where it used some other index?  If so, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

While we are at it, neither ordering in the `INDEX` is better.  That is, the cardinality of each of the two columns does not matter.

`ANALYZE TABLE JobTable` will refresh the statistics; it is fast, but imprecise, for InnoDB.